# Using getchar() to store address of string literal in char*pointer

Tags: c, pointers, getchar

The goal is storing the adress of a string litteral in a char*, which is a member of struct
id. I thought about using an array.
The problem with array is that, if I set the maximum number of character to 7, the user
might enter less than 7, so it will be a waste of memory.
The advantage using getchar() is that I can set max of char to 7, but if user enter less, that's ok too.

```
    typedef struct id
    {
    int age;
    char* name;
    }id;

    id Mary;

    char L;
    int c =0;

    printf("Enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d",&Mary.age);

    printf(" Enter your name: );

    if(  (L=getchar() != '\n'    )
    {
    // stroring string litteral in char*
 
    }


    printf("%s", Mary.name);
```

Comment: I don't really understand what your question is but you need to collect your data somewhere.  Currently you do not so you'll get memory faults.  Unusually you'd collect into a local stack variable/array of some size char[256] say, then allocate & strcpy from that to your final struct once you know the size.

Comment: The problem with this question is your use of the term "string literal".  The user input is a string _variable_, not a _literal_.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming).  It makes it very unclear what you are actually asking.

Comment: Yes you've right thanks

Comment: Aside: “literal” means something is described in its own text. A string literal `"abc"` contains the characters a, b, and c, because those letters are in the source text of the string literal. `char *name;` is not a literal because we will store arbitrary characters at `name`, not the characters in its text, n, a, m, and e. It is just a string, not a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem: "How do I read an input string of unknown length?" Daniel Kleinstein has mentioned several general solutions in his answer. I'll give a more implementation-based answer here

Firstly, your program does not try to store a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal), but a string read from an input stream (e.g. `stdin`).
Secondly, it is not possible to store a string "in a `char*`". The string is stored in memory pointed to by a `char*`. This memory needs to be allocated first.

The following code comes closest to what you want to do. It reads one character at a time and increases the size of the memory copied to by 1 byte every time.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int age;
    char *name;
} Id;

int main(void)
{
    Id mary;

    printf(" Enter your name: ");

    size_t nameSize = 0U;
    mary.name = NULL;
    while (true)
    {
        mary.name = (char*) realloc(mary.name, ++nameSize); // cast is optional
        if (mary.name == NULL)
        {
            printf("Memory allocation error\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        int ch = getchar(); // Note the `int` type, necessary to detect EOF
        if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF)
        {
            mary.name[nameSize - 1] = '\0';
            break;
        }

        mary.name[nameSize - 1] = (char) ch;
    }

    printf("%s\n", mary.name);

    free(mary.name);
}
```

This does not waste a single byte of memory, however, the frequent memory reallocations will make this code slow. A good compromise is to read one fixed length string at a time, instead of one character at a time.
To do this in practice: create a buffer on the stack of fixed length (e.g. 64 characters), read into that buffer using `fgets`, and copy that contents to `mary.name`. If the string didn't fit the buffer, repeatedly call `fgets` again, realloc `mary.name` and append the contents of the buffer to `mary.name` until you find a newline character.

Another, simpler solution is to set a maximum length for the string, allocate memory for that length, read a string of maximally that length, and finally reallocate the memory to the (possibly smaller) actual size of the string.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a magic bullet solution for this sort of problem.
Your options are:

- Use an array with a maximum length - but as you mentioned this can be wasteful if the user inputs a shorter length. Nevertheless this is usually the solution you'll find in real code - in practice, if memory isn't a huge concern, this is faster and simpler than trying to deal with other dynamic solutions that involve memory allocations.
- Ask the user for the length of their name before they input it - then you can dynamically allocate an appropriately sized buffer using either `char* name = malloc(input_length);`, or `char name[input_length]`; in C99+. You could also do something like a flexible array member:

  ```
  struct name {
        size_t length;
        char buffer[];
  };

  struct name* username = malloc(sizeof(*username) + username_length);
  ```
- If you don't want to ask the user for the length of the username, you can do a chain of `realloc` calls after each new `getchar`, which will resize a dynamically allocated array - but this a terrible idea which you shouldn't even consider unless you're stressed over every byte of memory consumed in your program.